# How can I call the same Action on every page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have the following `ActionResult` that I would like to call on my `_Layout` view.  The properties will be used to control what displays on the navigation bar:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GenerateLayout()
{
    var loseATonEvent = db.Events.Max(e => e.EventId);
    var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    currentUser = currentUser.Contains('\\')
        ? currentUser.Substring(currentUser.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1)
        : currentUser;

    var layout = new NavigationViewModel
    {
        IsAdmin = User.IsInRole("ITS-Dept"),
        IsSignedUp = ConfirmIsSignedUp(loseATonEvent, currentUser),
        CanSignUp = ConfirmCanSignUp(loseATonEvent),
        CanWeighIn = ConfirmCanWeighIn(loseATonEvent)
    };
    return PartialView("_Layout", layout);
}
```

From what I've seen, in order to do this, I need to use `@Html.RenderAction()`.  In my `_Layout` view, I have the following:

```
@{
    Html.RenderAction("GenerateLayout", "Navigation");
}
```

However, all this will do is create an infinite loop.  My question is, how can I avoid this?  Is there simply a way to return this view model?  Or is there a better way to go about this so that I don't need to call this after every page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach would be to utilize 'Session' data to contain your values, and then base your _Layout menu conditions on that data.

For example, when someone logs in...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  // validate user here
  if (validUser)
  {
    var loseATonEvent = db.Events.Max(e => e.EventId);
    var currentUser = User.Identity.Name;
    Session["isSignedUp"] = ConfirmIsSignedUp(loseATonEvent, currentUser);
    Session["canSignUp"] = ConfirmCanSignUp(loseATonEvent);
    Session["canWeighIn"] = ConfirmCanWeighIn(loseATonEvent);

    // return user to destination URL
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
  }
}
```

So now we have Session variables to use in conditionals to build our navigation.

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("ITS-Dept"))
{
  // add the nav element here for "ITS-Dept" users
}

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Session["isSignedUp"] == "true")
{
  // add nav element for this Session val
}

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Session["canSignUp"] == "true")
{
  // add nav element for this Session val
}

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && Session["canWeighIn"] == "true")
{
  // add nav element for this Session val
}
```

And you would just add those directly to your _Layout.  Session variables can be versatile.

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up going this route.

Answer (score 0):

If your navigation is self contained, then instead of returning `_Layout`, break your navigation into another partial and return that instead.

Your controller method will build the view model and return the navigation

```
return PartialView("_Navigation", layout);
```

_Navigation will contain your navigation markup and will determine what needs to be shown and what needs to be hidden using your view model.

_Layout, instead of having to retrieve the properties and determine what needs to be shown, just needs to render the action as-is.

Comment: So would my `_Layout` only contain the following: `@Html.RenderAction()` and the rest of the markup would be in `_Navigation`?  I believe I tried something like this and it complained that I was using `@RenderBody()` in my `_Navigation` view

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla, _Layout still calls RenderBody and will also call RenderAction("_Navigation"). _Navigation will just have the navigation HTML.